# Declare 2 class with same name but can't use namespace issue

Tags: php, namespaces

I created my own autoload for my cms. But when my project is getting bigger than i thought. I used namespace. but i realize that i can't use `use` inside my `autoload` function.
Is there anyway to load 2 class with same name but different namespace.
I have 2 class:
HumanDao.php:

```
class HumanDao extend Dao{
    public function __construct(){  
      parent::__construct();
    }

   public function doSomething(){
     .....
   }      
}
```

Monster.php

```
 class MonsterDao extend Dao{

    public function __construct(){  
      parent::__construct();
    }

   public function doSomething(){
     .....
   }
}
```

Dao.php

```
  class Dao {
   public function __construct(){
      loadAdapter();
   }
   private function loadAdapter($folder,$name){
      //load all adapters of a dao with their own model 
   }

   public function doSomething(){
     .....
   }
}
```

But my project's getting bigger than i thought.
I have 2 adapter with same name `BodyAdapter` but different in code, and loaded by different DAO and work with 2 different model,different folder. At first, i thought it's ok. Because each of DAOs only loads a `BodyAdapter`. But Php still throw out `Can't redeclare`. So i added namespace into each Adapter(namespace: Human,Monster). and try:

```
public function loadAdapter($folder,$name){
        use $folder;
        include $folder.$name;
        $this->name = $name::getInstance();
}
```

But php can't parse `use` keyword in a function.
So i'm stuck at here.
Could someone give me help me?

Comment: You cannot put a class into a namespace by using `use` when you try to `include` the class. You put a class into a namespace by using `namespace` when you define the `class`. And your loader doesn't need to use `use` at all. – Are you using `namespace` at all somewhere…?

Comment: in my current project, i didn't use  namspace. It was not big as now. Then how could i declare 2 class with same name in this situation?

Comment: You can't. You have to rename your classes using `namespace`. That's what it's for, to *give your classes a different name(space).*

Comment: my original project is non-namespace project. But in this situation i don't know how to  solve `redeclare` error of  Php

Comment: I gave them different namspace but  when i `autoload`. I can't call it without import namespace. But adapters are from many many namespaces. So i'm confused. Could u give me a hint?

Comment: i really don't know how to deal with `redeclare` error of Php now.

Comment: could u give me a example. Please.

Comment: `namespace A; class BodyAdapter {}`, `namespace B; class BodyAdapter {}` Without seeing what you're attempting and where exactly you're failing it's hard to give any other advice.

Comment: oh! i declared like that too but don't know how to call in another class. Because `dao` loads many `adapter` of many namespace. So i don't know how to call out in  `loadAdapter` function. As the above `loadAdapter` code, i use `use` keyword to load call another namespace. But can't. Could u show me how to call out dynamically  class `namespace A; class BodyAdapter {}`and `namespace B; class BodyAdapter {}` in `loadAdapter` function.

Comment: just give me  a hint please.